# What're the ways to predict a time series with seasonal and trend components?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend

I've got a time series with seasonal and trend components, the interval is 1 hour (the size of the input data is: 24 values per a day * 365 days), the task is to predict 24 values (for the next day).
What I've tried so far (with the help of *stats.stackexchange*, thanks!):

- Linear regression with multiple features (is_weekday, hour etc)
- FB Prophet
- ARIMA (SARIMAX)
- LSTM neural network

The problem is that though FB Prophet and SARIMAX perform the best, I can't integrate them in my Java code (I've found a few libraries on GitHub, but they generate some *random* forecast in practice).

I probably can hardcode the weights of my LSTM model into my Java code as well as use linear regression (there's a simple library for that).

Are there any other techniques to forecast a time series with seasonal and trend components I've missed?